# How to pronounce -ttle and -ity in american english?

Tags: pronunciation

I watched a lot of youtube videos that aim to teach how to pronounce words like **bottle** and **battle**. I listen to the American flapped T carefully but I still don't know how to repeat after them because this sound doesn't exist in my native language. I don't know how to move my tongue. Would you give me hints or tips to help me, please?

Also, when I try to pronounce responsibility, security, probability, possibility. They sound like responsibili**l**y, securi**r**y or securi**dd**y, probabili**dd**y, possibili**dd**y. My d sound is much more stronger than what Americans say.

Comment: What is your native language? Can you pronounce a T sound, even if it's not an "American flapped T"?  The British English T sound?  If you say "probabiliddy" and "probability", or "bottle" and "boddle" , over and over, the D and T aren't very different.. Find a lazy in-between sound.

Comment: My native language is Arabic and yes I can pronounce the normal T (like British T)

Comment: @Sam It's just the American flapped T that doesn't exist in my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't pronounce a flapped t, just use a regular t for words like *mettle*. We Americans will understand you perfectly fine, although it might contribute to an impression of a foreign accent.

If you use a "heavy d" for *mettle*, Americans might think you're saying *meddle*, so you might be misunderstood.